# Implementing Test case

Tags: unit-test

So i just started in salesforce. I am trying to implement a trigger in salesforce and run a test . So far i created the trigger and i am having a issue with the test. The test that i created failed saying that list has no row Account_Contact
Here is my trigger

```
trigger copyaddress on Account_Contact__c (after update) {

Map<Id,String> mapAccounts = new Map<Id, String>();
Set<Id> setAccountIds = new Set<id>();

List<Contact> lstContact = new List<Contact>();

for (Account_Contact__c t: trigger.new){

    setAccountIds.add(t.AccountContacts__c);
}

for (Account acc:[Select BillingStreet from Account Where Id in : setAccountIds]){
    mapAccounts.put(acc.Id,acc.BillingStreet);
}

for ( Account_Contact__c t: trigger.new){
    Contact c = new Contact(id = t.ContactAccount__c);
    c.Address__c = mapAccounts.get(t.AccountContacts__c);
    lstContact.add(c);
}

if(lstContact.size() > 0) {
    update lstContact;
}
```

}

Here is my test

```
@istest private class Account_Contactc_Tests{

testMethod private static void testCreateAccount(){
    Account act = TestDataFactory.BuildAccount('Recruter');

    insert act;
    Account  actCon = [SELECT Name, BillingStreet, AccountNumber From Account ];
    Contact  cont =[SELECT Name, Address__c,AccountId From Contact WHERE AccountId = :actCon.id];

   System.assertEquals(actCon.BillingStreet, cont.Address__c);
}
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need to insert and then update an `Account_Contact__c` as the trigger will only fire for "Account_Contact__c (after update)" and otherwise the query in your test will return no rows.

Comment: How would I do this?  Would it be Account_Contact__c = a;

Comment: Suggest you Google "apex test trigger" and review the various examples.

Answer (score 0):

Your unit test class should looks like below. Haven't tested this unit test class and didn't add all asserts.

```
@isTest 
public class AccountContactTest{

    static testMethod void testCreateAccount(){

        Account act = TestDataFactory.BuildAccount('Recruter');
        insert act;
        System.assertEquals('Recruter', acct.Name); /*Assuming you are passing account name to TestDataFactory.BuildAccount*/

        Account_Contact__c ac = new Account_Contact__c();
        ac.AccountContacts__c = acct.id;
        ac.name = 'Account_Contact 1';
        insert ac;
        System.assertEquals('Account_Contact 1', ac.Name);

        ac.name = 'Updated Account_Contact 1';
        update ac;
        System.assertEquals('Updated Account_Contact 1', ac.Name);

        Contact  cont =[SELECT Name, Address__c,AccountId From Contact WHERE AccountId = :act.id];


    }
}
```